# testfor a fake player on a scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to `testfor` if a fake player called MobHunger on a scoreboard objectives that is Stats. I tried this:

```
/testfor MobHunger[score_Stats_min=1,Team=Mob_Hunger]
```

but it doesn't work... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the 1.9 snapshots, you can use the scoreboard to test nonexistent players:
`/scoreboard players test (playername) (objectivename) (min) (max)`

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you are on 1.8+) Since you cannot test for a player that isn't in game, Try using an armorstand.

First, Summon an armorstand with the nbt tags NoGravity, Marker, and CustomName. (Ex.  `/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,Marker:1b,CustomName:MobHunger}`

To set it a scoreboard, you can use an entity selector in place of the player. This would work: `scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,name=MobHunger] stats 1`

You can also use an entity selector in the testfor command, it's just a bit different syntax. `/testfor @e[type=ArmorStand,name=MobHunger,score_stats_min=1]`

Also, just a tip: try transitioning over to the execute command rather than testfor, as with testfor you need an comparator and a different command that needs to target the entity (unless you need that comparator for lag or other purposes). With execute, you can do a command in the same command if it finds the armorstand with a score of 1 in stats. Ex. `execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=MobHunger,score_stats_min=1] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ stone` is much more efficient than using a comparator.

Comment: TBF, there *are* limited things you can do with fake players, such as using `scoreboard operations`, but `testfor` and it's more useful cousin `execute` (or any targeted command for that matter) need to resolve an existing entity to function, and fake players aren't entities.